# How to tell python that a string is actually bytes-object? Not converting

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have a txt file which contains a line:

```
 '        6: "\\351\\231\\220\\346\\227\\266\\345\\205\\215\\350\\264\\271"'
```

The contents in the double quotes is actually octal encoding, but with two escape characters.

After the line has been read in, I used regex to extract the contents in the double quotes.

```
c = re.search(r': "(.+)"', line).group(1)
```

After that, I have two problem:

First, I need to replace the two escape characters with one.

Second, Tell python that the str object `c` is actually a byte object.

None of them has been done.

I have tried:

```
re.sub('\\', '\', line)
re.sub(r'\\', '\', line)
re.sub(r'\\', r'\', line)
```

All failed.

A bytes object can be easily define with 'b'.

```
c = b'\351\231\220\346\227\266\345\205\215\350\264\271'
```

How to change the variable type of a string to bytes? I think this not a encode-and-decode thing.

I googled a lot, but with no answers. Maybe I use the wrong key word.

Does anyone know how to do these? Or other way to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always a little confusing. I assume your bytes object should represent a string like:

```
b = b'\351\231\220\346\227\266\345\205\215\350\264\271'
b.decode()
# '限时免费'
```

To get that with your escaped string, you could use the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) library and try:

```
import re
import codecs

line =  '        6: "\\351\\231\\220\\346\\227\\266\\345\\205\\215\\350\\264\\271"'
c = re.search(r': "(.+)"', line).group(1)

codecs.escape_decode(bytes(c, "utf-8"))[0].decode("utf-8")
# '限时免费'
```

giving the same result.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. I don't think bytes object should be displayed in characters, like `b'A'`. We all know that in computers all data is stored in binary form. What a bytes object means depends on how we interpret it. Before that, it just a string of 0s and 1s. So, it should be displayed as hexadecimal, like `b'\x41'`. If I tell the computer that it is a number, it should be 65 in decimal. If it represents letters, it's the letter A in utf-8. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The string contains literal text for escape codes.  You cannot just replace the literal backslashes with a single backslash as escape codes are used in *source code* to indicate a single character.  Decoding is needed to change literal escape codes to the actual character, but only byte strings can be decoded.

Encoding a Unicode string to a byte string with the Latin-1 codec translates Unicode code points 1:1 to the corresponding byte, so it is the common way to directly convert a "byte-string-like" Unicode string to an actual byte string.

Step-by-Step:

```
>>> s = "\\351\\231\\220\\346\\227\\266\\345\\205\\215\\350\\264\\271"
>>> print(s)  # Actual text of the string
\351\231\220\346\227\266\345\205\215\350\264\271
>>> s.encode('latin1')  # Convert to byte string
b'\\351\\231\\220\\346\\227\\266\\345\\205\\215\\350\\264\\271'
>>> # decode the escape codes...result is latin-1 characters in Unicode
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape')
'é\x99\x90æ\x97¶å\x85\x8dè´¹'  # convert back to byte string
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1')
b'\xe9\x99\x90\xe6\x97\xb6\xe5\x85\x8d\xe8\xb4\xb9'
>>> # data is UTF-8-encoded text so decode it correctly now
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'限时免费'
```

Your text example looks like part of a Python dictionary.  You may be able to save some steps by using the `ast` module's `literal_eval` function to turn the dictionary directly into a Python object, and then just fix this line of code:

```py
>>> # Python dictionary-like text
 d='{6: "\\351\\231\\220\\346\\227\\266\\345\\205\\215\\350\\264\\271"}'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(d)  # returns Python dictionary with value already decoded
{6: 'é\x99\x90æ\x97¶å\x85\x8dè´¹'}
>>> ast.literal_eval(d)[6] # but decoded incorrectly as Latin-1 text.
'é\x99\x90æ\x97¶å\x85\x8dè´¹'
>>> ast.literal_eval(d)[6].encode('latin1').decode('utf8') # undo Latin1, decode as UTF-8
'限时免费'
```